# Select two values and update

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to `SELECT id, some_complex_calculations FROM some_table` and then update `some_table` to insert `some_complex_calculations` into other column with appropiate id. How can I do it?

Comment: `UPDATE` existing rows, or `INSERT` new rows? Question isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE some_table 
SET other_column = some_complex_calculations 
WHERE Id = 5; #appropiate ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement then this is what you want,
UPDATE will replace existing row. But you want the row to be inserted I guess,

```
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE(YOUR_OTHER_COLUMN) 
VALUES(SELECT some_complex_calculations FROM some_table WHERE ID=4) #For Example
```